# Cannot NG-Repeat array from AngularJS data (League of Legends)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular. I am making a League of Legends application. It's not new by any means but a proof of concept.

Files

Index

```
            <body>

                <div ng-controller="SummonerController">

                <form class="well form-search">
                    <label>Search:</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="keywords" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Keywords...">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
                    <p class="help-block">Type in a LeagueofLegends.com Champion Name.</p>      
                </form>

                <pre ng-model="result">
                <h1>{{summoner.name.data}} </h1>
                <h2>Level: {{summoner.level}} </h2>

                <ul>
                 <li ng-repeat="matches in data">{{matches}}</li>
                 </ul>

                </pre>

               </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Controllers.js
              'use strict';

```
        angular.module('myApp', [])
          .controller('SummonerController', function SearchCtrl($scope, $http) {

            $scope.url = 'process.php'; // The url of our search

            // The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
            $scope.search = function() {

                // Create the http post request
                // the data holds the keywords
                // The request is a JSON request.
                $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.keywords}).
                success(function(data, status) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                    $scope.data = data;

                    // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
                    $scope.result = data; 
                    $scope.summoner = data.summoner;
                    $scope.matches = data.matches.array;
                })
                .
                error(function(data, status) {
                    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                    $scope.status = status;         
                });
            };

          });
```

process.php

```
            <?php
            // The request is a JSON request.
            // We must read the input.
            // $_POST or $_GET will not work!

            $apiKey = "71e73084-6c8e-44a3-b46e-9bc929cd70af";

            $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $objData = json_decode($data);
            $url = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $objData->data . '?api_key=' . $apiKey;

            $array = array("summoner" => array('level' => '', 'name' => ''), "matches" =>   array() );

            $data = curl_download($url);
            $var = json_decode($data, true);

            /* Set X for Array Loop */
            $x = 0;

            foreach($var as $key => $summoner) {
                foreach($summoner as $item => $value) {
                    if($item == "summonerLevel") 
                           $array["summoner"]["level"] = $value;
                           $array["summoner"]["name"] = $objData;


                      if($item == "id") {
                        $id = $value;
                        $matchDownload = curl_download("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/NA/v1.3/game/by-summoner/" . $id . '/recent?api_key=' . $apiKey);
                        $matchData = json_decode($matchDownload, true);

                        foreach($matchData["games"] as $item => $game) {

                            if(!empty($champ['winner'])) {
                           $array["matches"][$x]["winner"] = "Won"; 
                            } else {
                           $array["matches"][$x]["winner"] = "Lost";
                            }


                           $array["matches"][$x]["mode"] = $game['gameMode'];
                           $array["matches"][$x]["type"] = $game['gameType'];
                           $array["matches"][$x]["subtype"] = $game['subType'];
                           $array["matches"][$x]["createdate"] = $game['createDate'];
                           $array["matches"][$x]["ipearned"] = $game['ipEarned'];

                            /* Each Game's Champ */ 
                           $champdata = curl_download("https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion/" . $game['championId'] . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
                           $champ = json_decode($champdata, true);

                           $array["matches"][$x]["champion"]["name"] = $champ["name"];
                           $array["matches"][$x]["champion"]["title"] = $champ["title"];
                           $array["matches"][$x]["champion"]["level"] = $summoner["summonerLevel"];
                           $array["matches"][$x]["champion"]["id"] = $champ["id"];
                           $x++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $return = json_encode($array);
            echo $return;
            ?>
```

Example of Data-Returned

```
                [
                   {
                      "winner":"Lost",
                      "mode":"CLASSIC",
                      "type":"MATCHED_GAME",
                      "subtype":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
                      "createdate":1440261853283,
                      "ipearned":0,
                      "champion":{
                         "name":"Jinx",
                         "title":"the Loose Cannon",
                         "level":30,
                         "id":222
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "winner":"Lost",
                      "mode":"CLASSIC",
                      "type":"MATCHED_GAME",
                      "subtype":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
                      "createdate":1425360797949,
                      "ipearned":51,
                      "champion":{
                         "name":"Jinx",
                         "title":"the Loose Cannon",
                         "level":30,
                         "id":222
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "winner":"Lost",
                      "mode":"CLASSIC",
                      "type":"MATCHED_GAME",
                      "subtype":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
                      "createdate":1425185899166,
                      "ipearned":77,
                      "champion":{
                         "name":"Jinx",
                         "title":"the Loose Cannon",
                         "level":30,
                         "id":222
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "winner":"Lost",
                      "mode":"CLASSIC",
                      "type":"MATCHED_GAME",
                      "subtype":"NORMAL",
                      "createdate":1409209618048,
                      "ipearned":62,
                      "champion":{
                         "name":"Jinx",
                         "title":"the Loose Cannon",
                         "level":30,
                         "id":222
                      }
                   }
                ]{
                   "level":30,
                   "name":{
                      "data":"MEepMorp"
                   }
                }
```

1) Can I ng-repeat through the array's keys for matches?

In this instance, ng-repeat="matches in data" is returning an array with two items, both of which are arrays. So a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, ng-repeat="matches in data" will get to the first level of your object, then you have to do another to get to the second.

Question: Are you missing a comma there?

```
]{
    "level":30,
    "name":{
       "data":"MEepMorp"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not properly understand how ng-repeat worked.

Once I changed it to..
 Match Mode: {{item.mode}}

It worked fine.